# Can client receive data if server socket is closed just after sending data?

Tags: java, sockets, synchronization

I'm making chat program with JAVA socket
I got trouble in kicking client

I have to close server socket just after send *KICK-Message(Client realize that he is kicked after receive the message)*

Then, I meet such situation.

[image: The Situation]

In this case, can client get server's kick message?

In other words

If client execute `BufferedReader.readline()` after server socket is closed(but server socket sent kick-message already), can client read kick-message?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: OK, best answer. I'll try just after have dinner :D